# XRDP - Connect to the same session (multiple users)

Tags: remote-desktop, session, xrdp

I'm trying to setup a rdp server, but I have some problems with sessions. Basically the user should connect to the same (existing) session, but I can't find a solution featuring multiple users.

I tried setting the xrdp port to a certain number, but the problem was that every user connected to the same session. Of course user1 should not be able to connect to the session of user2. Setting the port to "ask-1" in the xrdp.ini goes into the right direction, but this can not be a solution because I can't expect the user to keep the port number in mind. Just basic skilled people should use the server.

Moreover I tried to use tightvnc, but I just got the same results.

I hope somebody could help me and solve my first question :)

Comment: After upgrading to ubuntu server 15 the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Ubuntu version, you can achieve your requirement easily.  if you are running ubuntu 14.10 or later, the xrdp package has been updated to version 0.6.1-1 which allows users to reconnect to existing session. (out of the box no need to change xrdp.ini file)

Another option is to perform a custom installation (using x11vnc). This type of installation allow the system to reconnect to existing sessions

Finally, you can configure your ubuntu system to have multiple users and have the xrdp solution working. to ensure that all users that needs access to xrdp sessions, you have create the ~/.xession file for each users or you configure your system to handle this process.

whatever the option you select, each user will create their own session and they will be able to reconnect to their own existing session

Reference links

[Custom installation xrdp on ubuntu 15.04 and later](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8342)

[Custom installation xrdp on ubuntu between 12.10 and 14.10](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5971)

[configure xrdp for multiple users](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6050)